# Can't start without X server in order to install video drivers

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, recovery-mode

On 10.10 I was able to make quick Video Drivers installs just by starting Ubuntu in "recovery mode", which would me allow to modify the X server. But now if I start the system in recovery mode it still starts the X server and all the `service gdm stop` and `service lightdm stop` commands won't work. `gdm` says it isn't a recognized command and `lightdm` simply turns off my screen. None of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*</kbd> combinations work. This is getting to my nerves.

Please! I just upgraded my system and I need to install the video drivers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses `lightgdm` and not `gdm`.

i had to do this once and used `sudo stop lightdm` & `sudo start lightgdm`

Comment: had to use it to have the guest account disabled.... it stated restart but this worked too and i checked it

Comment: No. As I said, if I do a lightdm stop command my screen go blank and I have to reboot holding the power button. I want to disable the x server on recovery mode, please!

Comment: This worked for me. sudo stop lightdm from the Ctrl-Alt F1 console. Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Please boot your computer with the kernel parameter nomodeset.

Please have a look at [this great how-to](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) for detailed instructions how to boot your computer.